# Нужна ли здесь запятая после слова "Однако"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, вводные-слова

"До французского, я учил немецкий и немного русский. Грамматика этих языков сильно отличается от грамматики испанского. Однако, с самого начала я был впечатлен тем, как похожа французская грамматика на испанскую, хотя они и не идентичны."
Правильно ли я понимаю, что здесь "однако" не вводное слово и запятая не нужна?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы правильно понимаете.

Розенталь даёт категоричный ответ.

**В начале предложения** (или части сложного предложения) либо при употреблении для связи однородных членов *однако* имеет значение противительного союза (не является вводным словом) и **запятыми не выделяется**:
*Однако хитрая политика отца ничуть не обидела его (Соб.); Канонада стала слабее, однако трескотня ружей сзади и справа слышалась всё чаще и , чаще (Л. Т.); Мы не надеялись никогда более встретиться, однако встретились (Л.).*

В редких случаях слово *однако* в начале предложения приближается по значению к междометию (выражает удивление, недоумение, возмущение) и отделяется запятой:
*Однако, какой ветер! (Ч.); Однако ж, надо пить кофе (Ч.); Однако, многого захотели!*

http://old-rozental.ru/punctum_uk.php?pid=226

Примечание: после "*До французского*" запятая не нужна.